# How do I find lowest upper bound and greatest lower bound when dealing with functions?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Here is my problem: I have to find the integer that is the highest lower bound for the roots of $$f(x)=x^4-3x^2+2x-4$$

I am not sure how to do this and the book I am using does not explain it very well. If you could explain to me how to find the highest lower bound and lowest upper bound that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The polynomial $f$ has two real roots, so I do not see the point of looking for the highest lower bound and lowest upper bound. Those would be the roots themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for an explanation of "how" so here is the explanation: Find $f'(x)$ of your polynomial and set this derivative$=0$. Find the roots of the derivative. The biggest root and the smallest root are your upper/lower bound answers. Plug these roots back into $f(x)$. The points $(x,f(x))$ (where x is the root of the derivative) are your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lowest upperbound, but there is a greatest lowerbound 
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-3x%5E2%2B2x-4)

To find it analytically:

Solve for all $x$'s (there should be 3) where $f'(x)=0$. Those are your local maxima/minima. To find whether they are max or min, you can do either 1 of 2 things.

First, you could do the Second Derivative Test. Take the 2nd derivative and see whether its positive/negative/zero, corresponding to min/max/saddle point respectively. Alternatively, you could just plug in near values and see whether if its max/min.

Edit: I guess if you want an integer, you will need to take the floor function at the end (if the root is not already an integer)